# How can I append values from one df to the bottom of a column in my second in one expression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to append a list of values ('A') from a separate df to the bottom of my output (finalDf) where the values are always the same and don't need to be in order.

Heres what i have tried so far:

```
temp1 = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].append(df1['A'], ignore_index = True))
temp2 = pd.DataFrame(df['B'].append(df1['B'], ignore_index = True))

print(df.shape)
print(temp1.shape)
print(temp2.shape)
```

shape output (example from my code with + 28 values from df1):

```
(11641, 6)
(11669, 1)
(11669, 1)
```

Where appending the values seems to work based on the shape of temp1 but I cant seem to apply the values from both Col 'A' and Col 'B' to the bottom of col 'A' in dfFinal together - it's always either col 'A' **or** col 'B' from df1 never both in df

TLDR; How can I best take the values from col 'A' and Col 'B' in df1 and append them to Col 'A' and Col 'B' in df to make dfFinal which I can then export to csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `concat` function along `axis=0` i.e. it will join the data frames provided along rows. In layman terms, it will join the 2nd data frame below the 1st. Keep in mind that the number of columns should be the same in both the data frames.

```py
df.concat([temp1, temp2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Over here, `ignore_index` ignores the new indexes that will be formed by concatenations and instead creates a new one from 0 to 'n-1'.

For more information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html