# I need to add to columns of same Dataframe into one from the end of the first column in Python

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, data-analysis

[image]

Suppose there are two columns A and B in the same Dataframe named DF.

Df[A] = 1,2,3,4,5 # This are column valuesjust for reference

Df[B] = 6,7,8,9,10

new_column should be A+B
such that the result be like :-

Df[new_column] = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: Is this what you meant to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822680/how-can-i-append-values-from-one-df-to-the-bottom-of-a-column-in-my-second-in-on/67822889#67822889.

Comment: You just need to use [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat)

Comment: This is the sql query but its not working in pyspark :                         
 sqlContext.sql('select MAX(COUNT(umpire1_name,umpire2_name)) as Occurrences Entire_dataset_table GROUP BY MAX(COUNT(umpire1_name,umpire2_name)) DESC').show()

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df[A], df[B]])